# Overriding Google Chrome javascript alert box maximum string length 2000

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert

Is it possible to override the maximum string length 2000 in a javascript alert box displayed in google chrome. If it is more that 2000 characters it is being trimmed and displayed with ellipses.

Thanks

Comment: Not going to happen with JavaScript....

Comment: what about using a modal like in bootstrap? if you don't want to use a framework for this, it's not hard to write it by yourself, fixed div with z-index and scroll functionality

Comment: The alert box is not really something that can be customized. You should better use a "pop-in", a popup inside the navigator view.

Answer (score 2):

I would recommend looking into creating a custom modal div if you want more control over the content of the alert box. If you have jQuery available there are a number of plugins that accomplish this easily: https://github.com/kylefox/jquery-modal for instance.

If this is not something that's going into production, but just a hack for debugging or something, you can just pop a new window, and write the content to that new window:

```
var newWin = window.open()
newWin.document.write('This is some content in the new window')
newWin.document.close()
```